# Can't install php7.0-imap

Tags: php, php7, imap

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1, have installed php7 back in August, but today I tried to install the IMAP extension and it is not letting me.

```
root@ip-XXX-XXX-X-XXX:/etc# apt-get install php7.0-imap
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0-imap : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) but 7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is results of apt-cache search php7-*:

```
libapache2-mod-php7.0 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
php-all-dev - package depending on all supported PHP development packages
php7.0 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
php7.0-cgi - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
php7.0-cli - command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
php7.0-common - documentation, examples and common module for PHP
php7.0-curl - CURL module for PHP
php7.0-dev - Files for PHP7.0 module development
php7.0-gd - GD module for PHP
php7.0-gmp - GMP module for PHP
php7.0-json - JSON module for PHP
php7.0-ldap - LDAP module for PHP
php7.0-mysql - MySQL module for PHP
php7.0-odbc - ODBC module for PHP
php7.0-opcache - Zend OpCache module for PHP
php7.0-pgsql - PostgreSQL module for PHP
php7.0-pspell - pspell module for PHP
php7.0-readline - readline module for PHP
php7.0-recode - recode module for PHP
php7.0-snmp - SNMP module for PHP
php7.0-sqlite3 - SQLite3 module for PHP
php7.0-tidy - tidy module for PHP
php7.0-xml - DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
php7.0-xmlrpc - XMLRPC-EPI module for PHP
libphp7.0-embed - HTML-embedded scripting language (Embedded SAPI library)
php7.0-bcmath - Bcmath module for PHP
php7.0-bz2 - bzip2 module for PHP
php7.0-enchant - Enchant module for PHP
php7.0-fpm - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
php7.0-imap - IMAP module for PHP
php7.0-interbase - Interbase module for PHP
php7.0-intl - Internationalisation module for PHP
php7.0-mbstring - MBSTRING module for PHP
php7.0-mcrypt - libmcrypt module for PHP
php7.0-phpdbg - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (PHPDBG binary)
php7.0-soap - SOAP module for PHP
php7.0-sybase - Sybase module for PHP
php7.0-xsl - XSL module for PHP (dummy)
php7.0-zip - Zip module for PHP
php7.0-dba - DBA module for PHP
```

Help?

Comment: It seems like you installed Ondrej PPA which might be missing php7-imap but is in the official repo.

Comment: Seems like you know the solution, care to share it?

Comment: Did you ever add the ppa?  Take a peak in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder.  If you added it, there should be a file in there, something like `ondrej-ubuntu-php-xenial.list`.  I would remove it, `apt update` and try to install -imap again.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have installed a PPA that offers a newer version of PHP (7.0.9) than the main repositories (7.0.8). But that PPA doesn't seem to offer a 7.0.9 version of `php7.0-imap`. So `apt` tries to install the newest version of `php7.0-imap` it's got available, the package from the main repos. That depends on the `7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3` package from the main repos, but the PPAs `7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1` isn't compatible.

You can either disable the PPA, if you don't really need PHP 7.0.9 instead of 7.0.8, or you can look for the PPA with 7.0.9 that includes `php7.0-imap` as well.

Answer (score 0):

It possible that you have get installed php7.0-common in an old version.

Check by: sudo dpkg --get-selections|grep php